# AWS IAM Conditional Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to provide access to an IAM policy on the condition that that specific resource has some tag key/value pair. It does not seem to be working, despite following the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys).

The IAM policy is as follows:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/environment": "dev"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have a S3 bucket (named `my-bucket-name`) with the tag: `environment = dev`. Can anyone explain to me why the following command fails?

```sh
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

```sh
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/file.json .
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

---

UPDATE: based off of **@Dennis Traub** and **@jarmod** responses, I edited this slightly to add the tag to the object in the S3 bucket, and I'm still unable to read the object. I also tried changing the condition to `"s3:RequestObjectTag/environment": "dev"` and still no-go.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, Amazon S3 does not support condition keys based on bucket tags, only on object tags. That’s why it doesn’t work.

Comment: S3 has partial support for [authorization based on tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#storage_svcs). Partial meaning only for object resources.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumption, @jarmod

Comment: So just to clarify, if I put these tags on the S3 object, it should work? Because I am not seeing that on my end. With a `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name` or with `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/object.json .`. I get an `Access Denied` and a `Forbidden`, respectively

Answer (score 0):

Building off of **@Dennis Traub**'s answer, to get this to work with a specific object in the bucket, the IAM policy must leverage the `"s3:ExistingObjectTag/environment": "dev"` condition. The following policy worked for me:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/environment": "dev"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```